# Cannot convert return expression of type 'Publishers.FlatMap<AnyPublisher<>, AnyPublisher<>>' to return type 'AnyPublisher<>'

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, combine

I am having difficulties fully understanding Combine. Here I have an issue where I can't seem to return the correct Output type.

How can I do this?

```
func test(ticketId: String) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> {

    campaignByTicketIdUseCase.execute(ticketId: ticketId)     // this is AnyPublisher<Campaign,Error>
    .flatMap { (campaign) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> in     // this is where the error is thrown

        guard let url = URL(string: "url"),
        validator.isParticipationValid(campaignIdentifier: campaign.identifier) else {
            return Result<Void, Error>.failure(HttpError()).publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        return AuthSession.shared.doRequest(request: request)
        .tryMap({ (_: Data, response: URLResponse) -> Void in
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                throw HttpError()
            }
        }).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
```

Comment: If nothing else, you are returning `campaignByTicketIdUseCase.execute(...).flatMap { ... }`, and appear to be missing an `.eraseToAnyPublisher()` there.

Answer (score 3):

Just like Rob said in his comment, I was missing a `.eraseToAnyPublisher()` after the `flatMap` operation.

```swift
func test(ticketId: String) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> {

    campaignByTicketIdUseCase.execute(ticketId: ticketId)     // this is AnyPublisher<Campaign,Error>
    .flatMap { (campaign) -> AnyPublisher<Void, Error> in     // this is where the error is thrown

        guard let url = URL(string: "url"),
        validator.isParticipationValid(campaignIdentifier: campaign.identifier) else {
            return Result<Void, Error>.failure(HttpError()).publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
        }

        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"

        return AuthSession.shared.doRequest(request: request)
        .tryMap({ (_: Data, response: URLResponse) -> Void in
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpResponse.statusCode != 200 {
                throw HttpError()
            }
        }).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()       // <-- this was needed to solve the issue
}
```